# Recursive program correctness proof of a simple python program that returns (x + y).

Tags: algorithms, induction

[image]

For $k \in \mathbb N$ we define $Q(k)$ as follows

$Q(k): $ let $x, y \in \mathbb N$ and $x$ is a multiple of $3$ and $k = x + y$, then $FUN(x, y)$ terminates and returns $x + y$

I will prove $Q(k)$ using induction

Base Case: let $k = 0 \to \text{iff } (x = 0, y = 0)$

By line 1, 2, 5 FUN(x, y) terminates and returns $0 + 0 = x + y$ as wanted

Inductive step: Let $k > 0$. Suppose $Q(j)$ holds whenever $0 \leq j < k$ [I.H]

What to prove: $Q(k)$ holds

Since $k > 0$, it follows that line 3-7 could run since line 1 is not satisfied.

Therefore two cases: $y > 0$ and $y <= 0$

Case 1: If $y > 0$, then line 3, 4, and 7 will run.

Since $0 \leq k - 1 < k$, this mean IH will apply to $FUN(x+3, y - 1)$

By IH, $FUN(x+3, y - 1)$ terminates and returns $x + 3 + y - 1$

By line 3, 4 and 7. $FUN(x, y)$ terminates and returns $x + 3 + y - 1 - 2 = x + y$ by algebra, and as wanted

Case 2: If $y \leq 0$, then line 5, 6, and 7 will run since line 1, 3 are not satisfied

Since $0 \leq k - 1 < k$, this mean IH will apply to $FUN(x - 3, y )$

By IH, $FUN(x - 3, y )$ terminates and returns $x - 3 + y$

By line 5, 6 and 7. $FUN(x, y)$ terminates and returns $x - 3 + y + 3 = x + y$ by algebra, and as wanted

Therefore $Q(k)$ holds as wanted

This is my attempt above, not sure if I'm correct. I'm pretty confused on how to use IH in this or if my input size is even good.

Comment: Lines 1 and 2 have no effect on the output of this function, so you either have a typo or a bug.

Comment: Just put the letters el in front of the if on line 3, then your proof goes through fine.

Comment: if x == 0 and y == 0, then returns 0.

Answer (score 1):

Your are almost right.

However there is a mistake when you say:
"Since $0\leq k−1 <k$, this mean IH will apply to $FUN(x+3,y−1)$"

You assumed that $k=x+y$ thus $(x+3+y-1)=k+2$ and you cannot apply the IH !

For a correct proof I would go for 2 steps:

First prove that Fun(x,0) return 0+x (by induction on x)

Then prove that Fun(x,y) return x+y (by induction on y)